# Installing MySQL in CentOS without permissions

Tags: centos, users, mysql, c++, database

I need to install a MySQL that doesn't need root. The reason for this is that I'm a user in a cluster, so I don't want to mess other people work. Said that, is there a way to have a "portable" MySQL with C++ connections? I don't need workbench, our team will be using shell and VI the whole time.

Already tried this two:  ["portable"](https://www.howtoforge.com/creating-a-portable-mysql-on-centos-6-and-ubuntu-11.10-linux-from-sources)  and  [MySQL RPM installation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/linux-installation-rpm.html) .

Thanks!